# How to define the type of TItem inside of generic class, or set class name as a variable?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

How can I create a class variable (or class alias) on top of the file and use that variable name later in the file?
My goal is to reuse (copy) this class in several places and change only the class type variable on top of the file. Otherwise, every time I copy this class, I have to replace all class names in the file, which is more than a thousand lines. Sometimes you just miss some of them.
Of course, not all classes have the same properties, and when I'll change the class name from Address to Employee, VS editor will highlight those parts -

> "Employee does not contain member called 'StreetNo'"

Then I will take care of that red squiggly lines.

Is it possible?
For example:

```
var model = Employee;  // Employee is a class
```

and below use it as follows:

```
model newInstance = new model();
```

I tried to use generics (TItem), but I cannot assign the type of TItem inside of generic class:

```
public class Foo<TItem> where TItem : Employee
{
    // where TItem : Employee - this part of code only sets constraint, but doesn't set TItem equal to Employee - (e.g. TItem = Employee)
}
```

This is a very basic example of a razor component, which in fact is a partial class. I just simplified the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use find/replace if you're already using copy/paste reuse? Could you refactor the code to reduce the amount of duplication?

Comment: I feel like you've misinterpreted who generics work. Constraining `where TItem : Employee` does all that you need. A using Alias helps you in copy-paste scenarios, but generics usually helps you avoid copy and paste code altogether. When the designer can't support generic type initialisation then you inhertit from the generic class with your typed implemenation, but Generics will work in Blazor with the correct syntax, so show the scenario where Generic did not work so we can show you a proper solution.

Comment: You need to start from scratch: why are you copy-pasting in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`using` aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias):

```cs
using Model = Employee;
```

And later in the code:

```cs
Model newInstance = new Model();
```